# Can the SVN and HTTP protocols be used safely on the same repository simultaneously?

Tags: apache, version-control, svn

We would like to evaluate whether the SVN protocol works better for our team than HTTP, but we don't want to commit to a full switch just yet.

Right now we have an Apache sever serving up our main repository. Can we safely use svnserve.exe to with the same repository so that a few of our developers can test it? My initial guess is that we can, but we don't want to risk corrupting our repository.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. The official SVN book has a chapter devoted to this situation: 
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.multimethod.html . There are some pitfalls but they have more to do with permission settings.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly, Subversion is designed to support concurrent access via multiple protocols, something which causes major problems with CVS. Not only can you use http:// and svn://, but also file:// (if you happen to be working locally on the machine, for example with a continuous integration tool or other post-commit hook) https://, svn+ssh://, etc.

In my experience, one method hasn't proven to be objectively "better" than the other, but there are certain benefits to each. For example, Apache is extremely adept at handling lots of accesses at one. On the other hand, if you're not already using Apache, or don't want to make it handle SVN traffic, the `svnserve` daemon is lightweight and quite performant. On my Macs, I set up svnserve using [launchd](http://developer.apple.com/macosx/launchd.html) to start up only when a request comes in, so it doesn't use any resources when there is no repository activity. What works best will largely be a factor of the access patterns you see in practice.